# How do I repeat a jQuery scroll event function for multiple elements?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm using a simple function to get an element to appear only when the window scrolls down to it. The problem is, my function is based on the element's ID -- but I actually have **multiple** elements, and I want the **same** function to work **independently** on each of them. So in theory, `#scroll-to` should really be a class, not an ID.  I know there must be a better way to do this than naming each of the elements `#scroll-to-1`, `#scroll-to-2`, `scroll-to-3` and rewriting the function over and over for each one, but I have no idea how !

Thanks!!

This is the basic function:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var hT = $('#scroll-to').offset().top,
       hH = $('#scroll-to').outerHeight(),
       wH = $(window).height(),
       wS = $(this).scrollTop();
  
  // when element is scrolled into view: 
  if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
        $('#scroll-to')
          .css( {opacity: 1});
   }
  
  // when element is scrolled out of view:
  if (wS < (hT+hH-wH)){
        $('#scroll-to')
          .css( {opacity: 0});
   }

});
```

Comment: Use a class and then loop over all elements, checking if you've scrolled to that element.

Comment: If I loop over the class, then what should I do with the "this" already in the core function?

Comment: Assign that variable before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change very little about your code to apply the targeting to multiple elements. As you suggested, you would use a class to select all of your target elements. You would then [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) over that collection and apply your positioning logic *within* the `each` handler. As the `window` properties do not change, you can leave those variable assignments outside of the `.each` handler.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  const $window = $(window);
  const windowHeight = $window.height();
  const windowScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

  $('.scroll-to').each(function () {
    const $this = $(this);
    const top = $this.offset().top;
    const height = $this.outerHeight();
    const isInView = windowScrollTop > (top + height - windowHeight);

    $this.css({ opacity: (isInView ? 1 : 0) });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.one {
  background: purple
}

.two {
  background: orange;
}

.three {
  background: powderblue;
}

.four {
  background: pink;
}

.five {
  background: coral;
}

.six {
  background: plum;
}

.seven {
  background: turquoise;
}

.eight {
  background: crimson;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-to one"></div>
<div class="scroll-to two"></div>
<div class="scroll-to three"></div>
<div class="scroll-to four"></div>
<div class="scroll-to five"></div>
<div class="scroll-to six"></div>
<div class="scroll-to seven"></div>
<div class="scroll-to eight"></div>
```